# Jenkins on Docker - Persist data

Tags: jenkins, docker, kubernetes

I have a docker container with a jenkins installation.
In order to persist the jenkins jobs, etc i have attached a disk and told jenkins to use it. No problem so far.

Now i have ssh into the machine to install the dotnet core cli. I have installed dotnet on the attached disk. After that a run

```
ln -s /dev/myDisk/dotnet/dotnet /usr/local/bin
```

to "register" the command. Works as expected. But if i restart the node "dotnet" is no longer in the /usr/local folder.

It makes all sense to me.

I have tried to find something but had no luck.

How can i run a script if the container starts or persist this data too ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes to a running container are not committed to the *image*, so if you restart, the changes you made to the running container are not persisted.

You have a few options:

1. Create a new image in which .NET core is installed
2. Use the
   "official" .NET Core docker image as your base:
   https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker

More information on Docker filesystems here:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/

Answer (score 0):

I ended up in

- configuring my container (as before)
- commit my changes to a new image
- pushed the image to google container registry (docker hub would work too)
- changed my deployment to use the new image